# Union of two tables in a 3rd table with additional flag column using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

One is  Promotion

```
| PromoId |Promo Decription|
----------------------
|   101   |  abc|
|   102   |  pqr|
|   103   |  alp|
|   104   |  adc|
|   201   |  abc|
```

and the other is PromotionType

```
| PromoId | PromoType  | 
----------------------
|   101   |  1   |  
|   121   | 2    |  
|   188   | 3    |  
|   104   | 4    |  
|   191   | 4    |  
|   102   | 4    |
```

I want a resultant table

```
| PromoId | Flag |Promo Decription |PromoType  |    
----------------------
|   101   |  1   |                 | 1 |
|   121   | 0    |                 | 2 | 
|   188   | 0    |                 | 3 | 
|   104   | 1    |  adc            | 4 |  
|   191   | 0    |                 | 4 |  
|   102   | 1    |  pqr            | 4 | 
|   103   | 1    |  alp            |   |
|   201   | 0    |  abc            |   |
```

i.e  I want a resultant table , which is the union of two tables  .It should not contain duplicate values and the value of flag is set to true for all the values of PromoId's which are common to both tables.

I am using Sql Server as our database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to perform this:

```
select 
  coalesce(p.promoid, t.promoid) promoid,
  case when p.promoid = t.promoid then 1 else 0 end flag
from promotion p
full outer join promotiontype t
  on p.promoid = t.promoid
order by promoid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eec7a/2)

Result:

```
| PROMOID | FLAG |
------------------
|     101 |    1 |
|     102 |    1 |
|     103 |    0 |
|     104 |    1 |
|     121 |    0 |
|     188 |    0 |
|     191 |    0 |
|     201 |    0 |
```

Edit, even with your changes to the data sample the query will still produce the result:

```
select 
  coalesce(p.promoid, t.promoid) promoid,
  case when p.promoid = t.promoid then 1 else 0 end flag,
  isnull(p.[Promo Decription], '') [Promo Decription],
  isnull(t.PromoType, null) PromoType
from promotion p
full outer join promotiontype t
  on p.promoid = t.promoid
order by 
  case when PromoType is not null then 0 else 1 end, promotype, promoid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/160f7/8)

Result is:

```
| PROMOID | FLAG | PROMO DECRIPTION | PROMOTYPE |
-------------------------------------------------
|     101 |    1 |              abc |         1 |
|     121 |    0 |                  |         2 |
|     188 |    0 |                  |         3 |
|     102 |    1 |              pqr |         4 |
|     104 |    1 |              adc |         4 |
|     191 |    0 |                  |         4 |
|     103 |    0 |              alp |    (null) |
|     201 |    0 |              abc |    (null) |
```

Comment: Thanks, for ur efforts. I have modified the question because using your solution , I was not getting the desired result set.
Please have a look at the desired result set.

Comment: @palakmehta I am not sure I understand, this query will still work see this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/160f7/2 or even this one -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/160f7/8

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script:

```
    select a.PromoID,
    coalesce((case when b.promoID=a.promoID then '1'
          when b.promoID<>a.promoID then '0'
    end),'0') flag
    from hr.promotion_type a
    LEFT OUTER join hr.promotion b
    on(a.promoID= b.promoid)
```

here, the HR is the schema I used, you can use your corresponding schema